# Map Two Finger Tap Middle Click touchpad Windows 10 Dell XPS 9360

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad, dell-xps, mouse-click

Using two finger tap for right click seems superfluous on a windows built machine, as I already have a right click button on the track pad. I am certain it is possible to use two finger tap for the middle click instead. Can anyone tell me how?

I have the laptop fresh out of the box. I can not find synaptics nor elan in regedit. Is there a way that it can be changed without installing new drivers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2023, Windows 11 still doesn't allow changing two-tap to middle-click. What's ironic is that in "Advanced gestures" for three-tap there are options "Middle mouse button", "Mouse back button", and "Mouse forward button", but no "Right mouse button".

In KDE such settings are available out of the box: <https://kde.org/announcements/plasma/5/5.3.0/touchpad.png>.