# Windows 10 Change TwoFingerTap to be middle-click

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, asus-laptop, mouse-click

My Question is basically the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1239062) except for an Asus Expertbook P1 and I'm fine with installing new drivers if necessary.

Is there some way to remap TwoFingerTap from right-click to middle-click?

Comment: Does [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1281830/disable-two-finger-click-for-right-click-but-keep-two-finger-tap) help? If not, what is your keyboard model?

Comment: @harrymc No - those registry keys don't show up when I search in regedit, and there's no `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\` folder in regedit. As for keyboard model, I don't know - how do I find that out?

Comment: Look in the Device Manager, perhaps under the branch "Human Interface Devices".

Comment: @harrymc Theres an 'ASUS Precision Touchpad' driver there, yeah, but what do I do with it?

Comment: So you have a Precision Touchpad, which is good. You may configure it as described [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-customize-precision-touchpad-settings-windows-10), but I think that only three-fingers tap will work.

Comment: @harrymc Ah. Yeah, I already did that. Ideally would like either two-finger-tap as middle-click or three-finger-swipe as scroll so I don't have to keep swapping between two and three fingers, though.

Comment: Long shot: Search the registry for an item(s) called `2FingerTapAction`. [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) can help speed it up.

Comment: @harrymc Nnnope, not there.